# Consequence of using both filevault and cloud encryption

Tags: filevault, icloud

I am using a macbook pro with filevault turned on. I am planning to start using a zero-knowledge cloud service (sync.com) for all my files, to have a secure backup and as a way to share certain files with others. I was wondering if the two types of encryption will work alongside each other. If so, where in the process does the cloud encryption engage, and where does filevault take over? Will there be unnecessary redundancy in the two encryptions (perhaps with longer waiting times)? 
Just trying to picture what will happen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On macOS, FileVault is encryption at rest so it’s designed to protect your files when the operating system isn’t operating. Just as you can see an email or text document once you log in and your password decrypts the drive, any apps can read clear versions of your files and send them to the cloud in the clear, print them in the clear.

Having FileVault doesn’t make things slower or faster, so you can pretty much exclude that from your worries and plans about whatever cloud sharing service and program you select.

That service will be fast or slow, secure or not on its own design and merits regardless of the status of FileVault.

Comment: It’s good you are asking questions - cryptography and encryption are very hard - as is changing your behavior to match the limitations and trade offs that are made by these systems/software. The more likely you lose your files forever, the more likely the protection is good from casual and unsophisticated attempts to access your data. Nothing is going to be truly secure, but hopefully you can add some level of security to protect against some threat models.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate you have taken the time to help me!